# Dynamic Programming: Retrieve all solutions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have successfully used DP to get optimal solution to a problem. The issue I am facing though is, now if I want to reconstruct the solution, I end up with only one such way to get optimal solution. Is there a way, such that I will be able to backtrack all the ways/choices which could have lead to an optimum result??

e.g If I am selecting a team from players a, b, c, d with skills {1, 2, 2, 1}, I can get that optimum team skill count will be 3 and I can get one possible way to achieve this as {{a, b}, {c, d}}. What I am looking for is, a way so that I can get all the ways in which I can divide the team fairly with team skill count as 3 i.e {{a, c}, {b, d}} and {{a, b}, {c, d}}

Comment: Hello, please provide the problem you have in a clear statement.As it stays it is very difficult to understand the question.Given the skill levels of all players, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

If X is the number of players. (X-1)! is the number of possible solutions. Then you can use a for loop with the possible solutions as your length, if the result is equal to your optimum team skill then store that result in an array.

Comment: Do you also need help for calculating the optimum team skill? If so, What kind of result would you want for a situation like {1, 2, 3, 1}?

Comment: I have written code to get optimal sum. (in your example, it would be 4).
Are you suggesting a brute-force way to solve the problem (using for loop over all possible solutions)??

Answer (score 0):

Main step in DP is to find solution of a problem by knowing solutions of a subproblems. That is done by finding minimal (or maximal) value of subproblems. With that you can construct a directed graph by connecting problem with it's subproblems that have minimal (or maximal) value. Like in last image on the [page](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/seqcomp/node2.html). To find all solutions just find all possible paths from the solution of whole problem.